# Cypress Connecting to postgres database issue

Tags: postgresql

running into a issue using cypress-postgres connecting to the database. Server has multiple databases along with multiple schemas. Tried multiple plugins, but can find a solution that will allow me to specify a particular schema in a database. Server is reachable over the vpn.

Will need to do this with sql database. Any help, better method suggestions welcomed.

Thank You! - Michael Frazier

IE: [Database Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8Fkx.jpg)

Error that is returned

```
no relation for home
```

Package.json has following dependencies:

```
   name": "tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Automated Tests",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "test": "cypress open"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": 
  },
  "author": "Michael Frazier 
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.2",
    "@testing-library/vue": "^5.8.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "cypress-commands": "^2.0.1",
    "cypress-downloadfile": "^1.2.1",
    "cypress-postgres": "^1.1.1",
    "cypress-postgresql": "^1.0.8",
    "cypress-real-events": "^1.6.0",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "pg-promise": "^10.5.8",
    "yarn": "^1.22.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@4tw/cypress-drag-drop": "^2.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@cypress/skip-test": "^2.6.1",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.9.1",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.11.2",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.21",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "cy-mobile-commands": "^0.3.0",
    "cypress": "^9.5.3",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "cypress-fill-command": "^1.0.2",
    "cypress-iframe": "^1.0.1",
    "cypress-mailosaur": "^2.6.0",
    "cypress-mochawesome-reporter": "^2.4.0",
    "cypress-msteams-reporter": "^1.0.3",
    "cypress-plugin-tab": "^1.0.5",
    "cypress-wait-until": "^1.7.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.6",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "pdf-parse": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1"
  }
}
```

Cypress.json has DB credentials in following format:

```
    {
  "trashAssetsBeforeRuns": true,
  "responseTimeout": 30000,
  "requestTimeout": 50000,
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 4000,
  "experimentalSourceRewriting": true,
  "experimentalStudio": true,
  "projectId": "aycmk8",
  "reporter": "cypress-mochawesome-reporter",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "reportDir": "cypress/report",
    "charts": true,
    "reportPageTitle": "Melos Report"
  },

  "db":
  {"user": "postgres",
    "host": "",
    "database": "",
    "password": "",
    "schemas": "sct",
    "port": 5432
  }
}
```

Plugin in cypress\plugins\index.js file:

```
module.exports = async (on, config) => {
  on('task',
    {dbQuery: (query)=> require('cypress-postgres')(query.query,query.connection)})
```

Spec file has following test:

```
describe("Database Health Tests", function () {

  it('should ping the database to ensure its active ', function () {
    cy.task("dbQuery", {"query":"select * from home"})
  });
```

Comment: Are you certain that the config value for `db.schemas` actually carries the plural-s in the end? I'd suspect this to be `db.schema`.

Answer (score 0):

Your dbQuery is missing the connection string:

```
cy.task("dbQuery", 
{
  query: "select * from home",
  connection: "your connection string"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you focusing on description of `cypress-postgres` in npm, they provided 2-ways to use :

- The first way : load your database connection via cypress.json by `require('cypress-postgres')`.
- The seconds way : set your database connection by yourself in `cy.task`.

#### The first way

This way may make you mistake, the example shows unclear parameter to you :

```js
// In cypress\plugins\index.js

module.exports = on => {
    on("task", {
        dbQuery:(query)=> require("cypress-postgres")(query.query,query.connection)
    });
};
```

I'm not sure `query.connection` come from. If you access to the dependency, you will see :

```js
// In require('cypress-postgres')

const pgp = require('pg-promise')();
const postgressConfig = require(require('path').resolve('cypress.json'));

module.exports =  function(query,userDefineConnection)  {
  let connection = postgressConfig.db
  if (userDefineConnection!=undefined){
    connection=userDefineConnection
  }
  const db = pgp(connection);
  return db.any(query)
}
```

So you can change `query.connection` to your variable.

Normally, module in `cypress\plugins\index.js` received 2-arguments `on` and `config`. The `config` will refer to `cypress.json`, you can get your database connection via `config.env.db` :

```json
{
  "env": {
    "db": {
      "user": "postgres",
      "host": "localhost",
      "database": "postgres",
      "password": "mysecretpassword",
      "port":5432
    }
  }
}
```

Now `cypress\plugins\index.js` should be :

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config

  on("task", {
    dbQuery: (query) => require("cypress-postgres")(query.query, config.env.db)
  })
}
```

In your `*.spec.js` :

```js
// ...

  it('set "Y" to db', () => {
    cy.task("dbQuery", { "query": "select count(*) as num_row from home" 
  }).then(result => {
      expect(result[0].num_row).to.equal('1')
    })
  })

// ...
```

#### The seconds way

This way assign database connection directly in your `*.spec.js` :

```js
// ...

  it('set "Y" to db', () => {
    cy.task("dbQuery", { 
      "query": "select count(*) as num_row from home",
      "connection": {
        "user": "postgres",
        "host": "localhost",
        "database": "postgres",
        "password": "mysecretpassword",
        "port":5432
      }
    }).then(result => {
      expect(result[0].num_row).to.equal('1')
    })
  })

// ...
```